# SharePoint Online - Modern Sites - Can we Customize the (+ New) Drop-Down?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

If you are using the newer Modern sites in SPO, they provide us with a nice New drop-down for creating a List, Library, Page, Event, News, etc.  The problem is this doesn't have any documentation (as usual).

**Question**:
Has anyone been able to customize this through PowerShell or otherwise?  Is this planned to be customizable?  Or are SharePoint sites no longer relevant outside of a dumping ground AKA web shared drive?

Comment: I certainly feel you're pain. There are workarounds, some of which i have included in my answer. More detail and i can possibly assist further.

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer is unfortunately No/Kinda.

However by adding content types to the library/list you will have custom items appear in the New dropdown. If you wish to have a one of the drop down items go to specific page then then you can set the default template to the content type. The template can actually be any link to a page or a document etc (and it doesn't necessarily have to create a new list item).

If you just want a custom button in the tool bar then this can be achieved with a List Menu Item in Sharepoint Designer (sigh) or you could try SPFX custom action.

If you are able to share you're specific use case, I may be able to point you to a firm solution.